# removing background from progress dialog

Tags: java, android, android-layout, progressdialog, android-styles

I use a custom progress dialog in my app. It's shown in the photo below.I want to edit two things.First, remove that black background that appears behind the circle.Second, increase the volume of the circle and change its color.

[image]

This is the style

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF4081</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

This is my code

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity.this,R.style.CustomDialog);
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProgressDialog is deprecated. You can create your custom progress dialog using alert dialog.

```
public static AlertDialog showProgressBar(Context context){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_custom_progress_bar, null);
    builder.setView(view);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    return dialog;
}
```

You can then instantiate the dialog so you can manually dismiss it. Use it like so.

```
AlertDialog dialog = showProgressBa(this); // this will automatically show the custom progress bar
// to dismiss
dialog.dismiss();
```

Here is your custom layout for the progress dialog.

```
//layout_custom_progress_bar.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
        android:max="100"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Your progress bar drawable. You can change the color by changing the values of `android:centerColor android:endColor android:startColor`

```
// progress_bar
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="200"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="1080" >

<shape
android:innerRadius="18dp"
android:shape="ring"
android:thickness="4dp"
android:useLevel="false" >

<size
    android:height="48dp"
    android:width="48dp" />

<gradient
    android:centerColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:centerY="0.5"
    android:endColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:type="sweep"
    android:useLevel="false" />

</shape>
</rotate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
dialog= new Dialog(mContext);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_layout);
dialog.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a swipe refresh layout for that function instead of removing the background from the dialog.

You can Implement it in java without adding it in the xml layout.

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity{

     SwipeRefrehLayout swipeRefresh;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        swipeRefresh = new SwipeRefreshLayout();
        swipeRefresh.setEnabled(true)

        //Set Colour Scheme
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(#FF6F00, #880E4F, #000000);

        showSwipeRefresh(true);
    }

    private void showSwipeRefresh(boolean show){

        if (show){
            swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(true);
        } else {
            swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know hi is not as per your question but you can try it.